# Servicestack LinkedIn Oauth2 with Webauthenticator Not Returning to App

Tags: oauth-2.0, servicestack, linkedin-api, xamarin.auth

Hi Am having trouble with Servicestack authentication with Xamarin.auth component.

when try authenticate with ServiceStack with WebAuthencator , am getting authenticated but am not able to return to app as in case of Xamarin.Auth only.

```
[Route("/my-session")]
public class CustomUserSession : AuthUserSession ,IReturn<CustomUserSession>
{
    public string GithubProfileUrl { get; set; }
    public string TwitterProfileUrl { get; set; }
    IRedisClientsManager RedisManager;


    public override void OnAuthenticated(IServiceBase authService, IAuthSession session, IOAuthTokens tokens, Dictionary<string, string> authInfo)
    {
        base.OnAuthenticated(authService, session, tokens, authInfo);
        var userAuthRepo = authService.ResolveService<IUserAuthRepository>();
        var userAuth = userAuthRepo.GetUserAuth(session.UserAuthId);
}

}
```

here is the RAW request from JsonServiceClient

```
GET http://sample.com/api/my_info HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Authorization: DotNetOpenAuth.WebServerClient.XSRF-Session=GGcwh7UvAe3R5ivrrAv7MQ; ss-id=5byYKQ5TYwmYqK3EQ5Vi; ss-pid=82ZTomRsZmdRTTA6dkMF; X-UAId=1
Connection: keep-alive
Host: sample.com

RESPONSE :
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Cache-Control: private
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
WWW-Authenticate: LinkedIn realm="https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization"
X-Powered-By: ServiceStack/4.0 Win32NT/.NET
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Fri, 25 Nov 2016 19:59:37 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

while the same call to /api/my_info in browser redirects to auth and gets the info.

Browser Request :

```
GET /api/my_info HTTP/1.1
Host: sample.com
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.99 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: ss-pid=pnxqAEU3ExIzrVZ8QdR/; ss-id=qCAkeAUDbQ+QRkZvIQgv; DotNetOpenAuth.WebServerClient.XSRF-Session=lFqnWxGQfdOZEF55MrLT_Q; X-UAId=1
```

Browser Respone:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-Powered-By: ServiceStack Win32NT/.NET
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 22 Nov 2016 20:38:37 GMT
Content-Length: 9443
Connection: keep-alive

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-us">
<head>
<title>Simple Snapshot of 11/22/2016</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<style type="text/css">
BODY, H1, H2, H3, H4, H5, H6, DL, DT, DD {
..............
```

Also JsonServiceClient gets ss-id but later calling authenticate service failing with 401.

Answer (score 2):

There's an example project with docs showing how to authenticate ServiceStack with Xamarin.Auth available at:

- [github.com/ServiceStackApps/TechStacksAuth](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/TechStacksAuth)

Comment: I have Followed the same solution but am stuck at redirectUri provided on LinkedIn.

Comment: Am Having Issue here

Comment: var userSessionInfo = jsonServiceClient.Get<UserSessionInfo>("/my-session"); It says WebServiceException not Found

Comment: @TechCruize A NotFound Exception means the Service you're trying to call doesn't exist. The demo uses that as an example of calling an Authenticated Service after you've authenticated, for the TechStacks example it calls this [Custom Service which returns the Authenticated Users Session](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/TechStacks/blob/master/src/TechStacks/TechStacks.ServiceInterface/SessionInfoServices.cs).

Comment: I have trouble in getting the session Info from a service as mentioned in above link. when i use /my-session in browser i will be able to get nice formatted HTML with info , however when using JsonServiceClient.Get("/my-session"); am not getting session info.

Comment: @TechCruize Obviously I can't tell what's wrong from here with no context or hope to repro. But for interop issues like this you should be looking to inspect the raw HTTP Headers (using something like Fiddler) and then check the request to make making the request to the right URL with JSON **Accept** Header. What does `var json = $"{baseUrl}/my-session".GetJsonFromUrl();` return? and are you deserializing it in the right Response Type, e.g. `client.Get<CustomUserSession>("/my-session");` ?

Comment: I Have checked with the Headers Accept and its application/json as expected, but how can i know what response type am getting from client.Get<>? i have IReturn<CustomUserSession> and a typed client , but am not getting the session info , however cookie contains session id and Pid .

Comment: return new Account(userSessionInfo.UserName,jsonServiceClient.CookieContainer);

Comment: @TechCruize If you have an `IReturn<CustomUserSession>` marker you wont need to specify it on the call-site. Please update your question with the raw HTTP Headers + Response. Also what is this `new Account(userSessionInfo.UserName,jsonServiceClient.CookieCon‌​tainer)`? The `CookieCon‌​tainer` is a transparent collection the Service Client maintains itself, it shouldn't be touched or returned in a Service or anything like that.

Comment: Thank you for the help, i will update my question meanwhile the return new statement is as provided in TechStack.Auth[link](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/TechStacksAuth/blob/master/src/TechStacks.Auth/TechStacks.Auth/MainActivity.cs) at line 40

Comment: @TechCruize ok cool that's just the Xamarin.Auth [Account](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Auth/blob/master/src/Xamarin.Auth/Account.cs) object, I thought you were trying to serialize a new DTO and return the CookieContainer from your Service.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126164/discussion-between-tech-cruize-and-mythz).

Comment: Issue not resolved yet , can any one let me know how do i deserialize response from a JsonServiceClient .? Just a simple example of getting a session object from a service

Comment: @TechCruize Exactly like any other Service, it's still just returning a populated DTO. Can you please post the raw HTTP Headers, it's the best way to tell what's going on.

Comment: GET /api/my-service HTTP/1.1
Host: myhost.com
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: ss-pid=pid; ss-id=id; DotNetOpenAuth.WebServerClient.XSRF-Session=Ror_GAW6C1jarjrNzfAfGQ; X-UAId=1

Comment: @TechCruize ok can you also send the raw HTTP Response Including the body (you can scrub sensitive info), please update the question instead of putting code in comments. Also are you scrubbing the ss-id/pid Cookies? As they don't have real values?

Comment: Am getting Error Type Definition Expected { got <!DOCTYPE... how do i deserialize data from service to local userSessionInfo. Is ter any way that i can get Session with ServiceStack Authenticator

Comment: @TechCruize This is likely an error HTML page, which should contain the a Exception details inside it.

Comment: ok mythz  yes am getting ss-id and ss-pid here we go               HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Sat, 22 Oct 2016 00:03:35 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319 response is text/html  the last comment

Comment: @TechCruize Please post the **full** HTTP Request + Response Including their body in the **question**, please make it clear what info you're scrubbing, the ss-id/pid Cookies don't need deleting, they're just random strings.

Comment: I have updated the question,  am quite confused. Even though it took more time am exploring a lot thanks for the help.

Comment: @TechCruize It looks like you made this request from a web browser? We need the Request/Response from the JsonServiceClient which should return a JSON Response. But this Service is returning a UserSession DTO so there's no issue with this request, but this isn't going to identify the issue with the JSON client Request which is what we need the raw HTTP of to find out.

Comment: added JsonServiceClient  runtime screenshot

Comment: @TechCruize the screenshot just shows its a normal request but doesn't contain the info on what it's a request of. What exactly is the issue? Does the request throw an Exception? If it does include all the Exception info. If the issue is something else please specify exactly what.

Comment: Could you suggest how can i get network traffic of xamarin app in VS or XS .?

Comment: You can use fiddler

Comment: the issue is that when i add [Authenticate] attribute even for a simple service am getting the same error. why is adding that attribute resulting in error, even though i have Authenticated client why am unable to get info . Any comments are appreciated am stuck with this.

Comment: @TechCruize If adding `[Authenticate]` results in an error, then it suggests that you do not have an authenticated client. The purpose of the `[Authenticate]` attribute is to ensure only authenticated users can access that Service - an error indicates the request was not authenticated. Like I've asked for repeatedly above we need to see the raw HTTP Request/Response headers  of both the authentication request + failed service request in order to see what's actually happening.

Comment: Added Header info, when i first call /api/auth/LinkedIn client , it authenticates and subsequent requests to auth service responded, where as per TechStack.Auth sample if i call /api/my-session , if i call directly api / my-session wont automatically redirects to auth nor authenticated

Comment: Hi mythz i got the Request/Response Headers could you pls tell me whats wrong here , Auth header is also present then why am getting 401.

Comment: @TechCruize Your C# Client Request doesn't include the `ss-id/ss-pid` [Session cookies](http://docs.servicestack.net/sessions) (like the Browser Request has) for some reason they've been added to the `Authorization` HTTP Header which doesn't do anything.

Comment: Json Client`s CookieContain already contains cookies but its not sent over the request, till now tried many tricks but still no go , could u ssuggest me hw to set cookie explicitly here.

Comment: @TechCruize If it's populated in the `JsonServiceClient.CookieContainer` then it should be sent with the Request. You can also [send Session Cookies using HTTP Headers](http://docs.servicestack.net/sessions#use-http-headers-to-send-session-cookies), e.g. `X-ss-id`, `X-ss-pid` and `X-ss-opts`.

Comment: GET /api/my_info HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
X-ss-id: AMYnKFj5asGxg/MRVSOz
X-ss-pid: TNSRDTixMDKhF9VDAsLJ
X-ss-opt: perm
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Host: sample.com         Still 401

Comment: @TechCruize the cookies need to ref an authenticated session which you'll be able to see with the response cookies from the previous authenticated request. If it's using the same Cookies from the successful auth response then try removing the X-ss-opt header as you may not have authenticated with ?RememberMe=true.

Comment: Thanks @mythz got it :)